# ASP .NET CORE - Is there any way how I can check if user coming from intranet or internet through vpn

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

We have application where we have Intranet users and External (Internet) users who can access aplication only when they are connected to our VPN. I need to know if request coming from Intranet or External users, is there any valid way to do that?

If I know that, I can manipulitate with login type, so if request coming from Intranet i will send them to Windows authenticate in other case they must go through web login (Database check).

Comment: `i will send them to Windows authenticate` that happens automatically when you use IIS, before your application even receives the request. How is your web app hosted?

Comment: VPNs generate addresses in specific IP ranges, so you can detect whether the request came from a VPN connection or not.  On IIS you can create two separate virtual directories, one for Windows authentication and one for the other auth mechanism. Each one can have restrictions that allow only specific ranges to connect. You may even be able to create a redirection rule that sends requests from the VPN range to the VPN virtual directory

Comment: I have windows and anonymous auth, and i taught to put middleware and check if user is intranet or internet, however your second comment sound really good, do you have documentation for that or smth like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use services like ipinfo.io

They provide a lot of user connection information one of which is detecting if the user is using a VPN or proxy.

documentations: https://ipinfo.io/developers

It already has a lot of different language libraries, and C# is one of them. https://github.com/ipinfo/csharp

Comment: They have like 50k requests for free plan and i don't know how much requests do we need per month. But definitely, I wiil read documentation. Thanks !

Comment: Libraries like these do nothing more than what you can already do with `tracert`. Besides, company VPNs generate IPs in a very specific range. It's easy to check if the request comes from a specific range

Comment: That's the whole purpose of `ipinfo` lib, they have all these specific ranges.